# How can I merge split digits into one number?

Tags: javascript, numbers

I need to write a function which takes a number and returns the largest number that can be made with the same digits.

So far I've got:

```js
function largestNumber(num) {
    var digits      = num.toString().split('');
    var splitDigits = digits.map(Number);
    splitDigits.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
    return splitDigits
}
```

This returns the number in the correct order but the digits are split.   E.g. `123 = [3, 2, 1]`

- is there a way I can return `321` as a whole number?

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the array to return number:

```
function largestNumber(num) {
    var digits = num.toString().split('');
    var splitDigits = digits.map(Number);
    splitDigits.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});
    return Number(splitDigits.join(''));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to make it back a number

```js
const largestNumber = n => +[...n.toString(10)].sort((a,b)=>b-a).join('')
 
console.log('123 ->', largestNumber(123 ))  // 321
console.log('152 ->', largestNumber(152 ))  // 521
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

it may also be a good idea to check if the argument is an integer

```js
function largestNumber(n)
  {
  if (!Number.isInteger(n)) return 0
  return +[...n.toString(10)].sort((a,b)=>b-a).join('')
  }
```